# Code migration from python 2.6 to 2.7 pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am migrating code from python 2.6.6 to 2.7.5. While importing pandas i am getting below error

> > > import pandas
> > >         Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 39, in 
> > >           from pandas.core.api import *
> > >        **version** = str(get_versions()['version'])
> > >       KeyError: u'version'

Can you please help me

Comment: Can you post a code that reproduce the error ?

Comment: HI I have edited in the post. Can you please help me

Comment: Have you read that ? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12084